# MonoDevelop's refactoring operation seems to convert foreach into slower for loop?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

This is my code

```
foreach (Company company in core.GetCompanies("Dual"))
{
    Console.WriteLine (company.Name);
}
```

However, `MonoDevelop` 's static code analysis has an option to convert this into optimized `for` loop.

This is `MonoDevelop`'s optimized code,

```
for (int i = 0, maxLength = core.GetCompanies ("Dual").Length; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    Company company = core.GetCompanies ("Dual") [i];
    Console.WriteLine (company.Name);
}
```

Why is the second snippet more optimized than the first? Isn't the second one making multiple calls to the same function? I've actually measured it and the first one is faster than the second; I used a `StopWatch` to count the `ticks`:

**`foreach`**
12,843,440 ticks

**`for`**
63,266,749 ticks

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Both codes do the same thing. The one with the for loop will be faster. Also both of those can be optimized a bit more of those are the only lines in them.

Comment: Even ReSharper suggests things that are suboptimal, downright harmful, or plain wrong. Don't blindly trust tools that are just applying simple rules. In this case I suspect it's not suggesting an optimization, but rather a simple rewrite of a `foreach` into a `for` loop.

Comment: @deathismyfriend, they only do the same thing if `core.GetCompanies()` doesn't do different things if called multiple times.

Comment: @Joey the only thing yard is a name property which is a string.

Comment: The only way to answer this is to compile both and disassemble and look at the IL. I believe the Expression.Resolve on this in mcs would end up with basically the same IL, but without knowing actually what the 'core' class is anything is a guess.

Comment: @Eser, but they already know which is faster (point 1 in that article) and what a better understanding (point 2, and makes points 3 and 4 irrelevant, 5 part of what they want to consider and would better-equip them to deal with point 6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the enumerators in C# are not considered high-performance. However, MonoDevelop's attempt to optimize the enumerator away is horrible in this case.  Assuming GetCompanies() returns an array, the optimized code should look like this:

```
Company[] companies = core.GetCompanies("Dual");
for (int i=0; i<companies.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (companies[i].Name);
}
```

There is a chance that the compiler would use an indexer like this instead of using an enumerator.  Therefore, this code may perform exactly the same as the original code.